# How can I hide a route from users in Angular2 without them being able to manipulate the clientside code and access the route?

Tags: php, ajax, angular

I know about guards and I am using them.

However, guards are client side code which the user could manipulate so they could access the guarded route anyway, thus bypass the guard.

My entire Angular2 application has a PHP backend so I'm thinking of using that with AJAX somehow but I can't figure out a solution where they can't modify the AJAX response and access the guarded route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot prevent the user from accessing a part of the UI, nor from requesting or submitting data from/to arbitrary URLs on your server, nor inspecting the network traffic in detail.

Client side routing guards and permissions checks are basically a UX concern, to only provide the user with the UI elements for the functionality they are allowed to perform.

It is the server application's job to "really" implement data security and deny access to perform sensitive functions and access sensitive data, using authentication tokens, roles and permissions, and the like.

The result is that if a user accesses the guarded route by bug or by trickery, this route's component will request the secure data from the server (this data must not be included in the angular2 component), or attempt to perform a restricted action, but the request will fail because the user's security token has insufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide ajax calls being made in a browser. All popular browsers let you inspect network traffic.

As far as I know, you can't modify the response of an Ajax call unless you have a middle man between the browser and the server. However, you can't stop the user from modifying ajax requests.

They can make the same requests (made by the browser) through curl, wget, Postman, etc. So, if you want to have restrictions on a private route, make them login and check credentials on the server side.